# How to avoid sending variable from controller to lay-out : yii

Tags: php, yii, widget

I have created a new lay-out for my Yii web app. Within the Web-app, as well, I call a widget that takes in a variable $id. Currently, my widget is getting the data $id from the controller in which I have declared a public variable like so and I update it when I call the function index.

In controller

```
public $id; 
public function actionIndex($id)
{
    $dataProvider= new CActiveDataProvider('Recipient', array('criteria'=>array(
                                            'condition'=>'list_id = '.$id)));
    // resets the id so that $id can be captured inside the layout  
    $this->id = $id;

    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'id'=>$id,
    ));
}
```

In my Lay-out I use this $id like so. 
Layout.php

```
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>

    <?php 
      $this->widget('ListSummaryWidget', array('id'=>$this->id)); 
    ?>

<?php $this->endContent();  ?>
```

And then finally in my widget I use that id.

```
class ListSummaryWidget extends CWidget
{
/**
 * @var CFormModel
 */


public $id;

/** 
*  
* This function renders the view. It passes in the $id and returns  
*  the total due, numper of people, available accounts and the 
*/  
public function run()
{
    $id = $this->id;
    $this->render('ListSummaryWidget', array(
        // returns the total amount that is due in a paylist 
        'totaldue'=> Recipient::model()->totaldue($id), 
        ));

}
```

Now this works. However, I realize that if I ever want to use that widget again, I have to constantly call `$this->id = $id` in every controller's function that  I do. This makes me feel like I am doing something wrong/that there should be a better way to pass this data into the widget. How could I better pass data into my widget?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the widget. I see a problem that you created dependency between the layout and the controller and every time you are using this layout, you should call $this->id = $id in controller. This topic might be useful http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/4473-how-to-pass-variable-to-a-layout/

Comment: In some of your questions, you are referring to "layouts" as "lay-outs". They are not the same thing. Better stick with "layout"